# Is there any jurisdiction where this booby trap is legal?

Tags: criminal-law, property

It's been well established through other discussions here that booby-trappping one's property is both tortious and illegal in the United States.

My question is whether it's known to be legal in *any* other jurisdiction in the Western world (i.e., Europe, the Americas, Australia, and New Zeland).

I'm specifically interested in the sort of booby trap depicted in the following videos, where a bicycle or backpack is inconspicuously tied with a long rope to a pole or a tree and left in public view.  A would-be thief dons the backpack or mounts the bicycle and tries to make off with it.  After a few metres the rope jerks the thief back.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-gV8ICIcao

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83Aq52eR1zs

Now, both these videos appear to be shot in the US, where the scenario they purport to depict would be illegal.  Many have speculated that the videos are therefore completely staged (i.e., the "thieves" are stuntmen who know about the rope in advance).

However, let's assume for the purposes of this question that someone has decided in earnest to deploy booby traps in this manner, not for the purposes of making entertaining videos but solely to protect their property from theft.  Let's also ignore the issue that such traps are not foolproof, since many thieves would notice the rope before attempting to take the property.  Finally, let's further disregard the issue of civil liability.

Now, is there anywhere in the Western world where such trapping would be legal—that is, where the owner of the property would incur no *criminal* penalty from setting the trap, possibly even if a thief were injured as a result?  If so, does it make any difference whether the trapped item is left on public property or on one's own private property?

Comment: If a form of stupidity isn’t legal in the USA then it definitely isn’t legal anywhere in the Western world.

Comment: Edited title to make it clear that a specific booby trap is in question. Some less harmful booby traps (e.g. anti-climb paint) might be legal even without warning signs in some jurisdictions and situations, whereas explosive booby traps are going to be illegal pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Here's one "less harmful" booby trap: They have exterior wall paint designed to be applied to the first 1 meter off the ground. If hit with a water stream, it bounces the water stream back. Anyone urinating on the wall gets urine all over their pants and shoes.

Comment: In UK, the [Bird v Holbrook 1828](https://www.casebriefs.com/blog/law/torts/torts-keyed-to-epstein/intentionally-inflicted-harm-the-prima-facie-case-and-defenses/bird-v-holbrook/) ruling was that the defendant was not permitted to set a spring gun trap to protect his property.